# Breeze server-generated keys of guids saving temporary client keys to database

Tags: breeze

I have set up a breeze app with entities set to `autoGeneratedKeyType` of `Identity`. My database uses `char(32)` guids for primary keys, which are generated as defaults on the PK columns, which are NOT set as identities.

Upon save, the record gets created in the database, but it saves with the temporary breeze generated keys of 'undefined-1', 'undefined-2' etc.

Can breeze handle this type of server-side key generation scheme? What are my options? I must stick with this key generation approach due to the design of the existing system. Generating guids on the client comes to mind...

Have you got any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are working with Guid's, I think best practice should be to generate them on the client.  You can use the *breeze.core.getUuid()* method ( currently undocumented) to generate client side Guid's.

If you really want to generate them on the server, then you will need to use a Breeze KeyGenerator. There is more information on this topic here: [Search for Key Generator within this page](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/extending-entities) and within the API docs.