# Added Entitties don't change entityState after entityManager.saveChanges()

Tags: breeze, entitymanager

I create a new Entity in EntityManager like this:

```
var newCust = manager.createEntity('Customer', { Name: 'MyNewCustomer' });
```

it's Id is correctly generated. On a Button-Click I save the Entity on the Server:

```
manager.saveChanges([newCust]).then(function (saveResult) {
  alert('saved!');
}
```

Now everything works perfect BUT, the Entity in newCust keeps it's EntityState "Added". It doesn't change to "Unchanged".

I've debugged a little and found out, that in the function "mergeEntity(mc, node, meta)" of breeze, where the following code happens - no entity is found (eventhough the key it searches is the same Id - the Id-Fixup worked correctly):

```
var targetEntity = em.findEntityByKey(entityKey);
```

So everytime I save my new Entity, a new Entity will be created in my EntityManager. When I reload the page, the entity is flagged correctly and works. The only problem is, that a new entity will be saved everytime I save changes.

Thanks for any help!

**Edit 1:**

I found the problem and I'm not sure what exactly Breeze expects of me. When my ContextProvider saves the Entity it sends a DB-Update-Command (for all the properties) and then returns. The problem is, that the Id of the saveResult-Object is still the "tempId" and not the real one - so when Breeze on Client-Side receives the object it doesn't find it in the entityManager anymore because the Key-Fixup happened already.

What exactly is Breeze expecting to receive from the saveResult? A representation of the object as it is in the Database at this moment? - would make sense but I don't find it documented.

**Edit 2:**

It looks like I'm not able to replace the object in the saveWorkState.saveMap (EntityInfo info.Entity is readonly). What I would like to do is create the newly added object and return this object instead of the one that breeze sent me. I have calculated values on the newly created object and the new "real" Id. What the NoDB-Sample seems to do is just overwrite the Id for the newId but any other properties are not changing. Maybe I'm not using this mechanism right?

Comment: What is the entity's Id type and how are you generating it?

Comment: It's a GUID and it's generated temporary on client-side and then generated "for real" on the server-side. So the question is: in SaveChangesCore do I have to swap the Entities in saveWorkState with a new Version of the objects that I "get" from the DB? So I have to query each object from the DB?

Comment: Actually, the easiest way to let Breeze manage the merging of your 'temp' vs 'real' GUIDs is to implement your own Breeze KeyGenerator. See if this post may help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16699515/breeze-server-generated-keys-of-guids-saving-temporary-client-keys-to-database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make sure, that all EntityInfos that are returned in my SaveResult are the latest representation of the Database I just clear the saveWorkState.SaveMap-Lists

```
saveWorkState.SaveMap[n].Clear()
```

and add the new representations

```
saveWorkState.SaveMap[n].AddRange(newEntityInfos);
```

and for every Entity that is Added or Modified I create a new EntityInfo with the object that is returned by the Database

```
    private EntityInfo SaveEntity(List<KeyMapping> keyMap, EntityInfo info) {
            EntityInfo result = info;

            switch (info.EntityState) {
                    case EntityState.Added: {
                                    // CreateInDatabase
                                    // Possible changes in object properties happen (for calculated values)
                                    ...
                                    var newObj = GetObjectAgainFromDatabase(info.Entity);
                                    keyMap.Add(new KeyMapping() { EntityTypeName = bu.RuntimeClass.FullName, TempValue = (MyObject)info.Entity.Id, RealValue = newObj.Id });
                                    result = CreateEntityInfo(newObj, EntityState.Added);
                                    break;
                            }
                    case EntityState.Deleted: {
                                    // Delete in Database
                                    // EntityInfo doesn't have to change
                                    break;
                            }
                    case EntityState.Modified: {
                                    // Update in Database
                                    result = CreateEntityInfo(bu.WrappedPOCO, EntityState.Modified);
                                    break;
                            }
                    default: //EntityState.Detached, EntityState.Unchanged
                            break;
            }

            return result;
    }
```

Any comments on this solution are welcome!